# Ruby Regex - If the string is more than 10 characters, remove the first character if it is a "1"

Tags: regex, ruby

Without using a gem, I just want to write a simple regex formula to remove the first character from strings if it's a 1, and, if there are more than 10 total characters in the string. I never expect more than 11 characters, 11 should be the max. But in the case there are 10 characters and the string begins with "1", I don't want to remove it.

```
str = "19097147835"
str&.remove(/\D/).sub(/^1\d{10}$/, "\1").to_i
```

Returns `0`

I'm looking for it to return "9097147835"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your pattern, but add a capture group around the 10 digits to use the group in the replacement.

```
\A1(\d{10})\z
```

For example

```
str = "19097147835"
puts str.gsub(/\D/, '').sub(/\A1(\d{10})\z/, '\1').to_i
```

Output

```
9097147835
```

Another option could be removing all the non digits, and match the last 10 digits:

```
\A1\K\d{10}\z
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `1\K` Match 1 and forget what is matched so far
- `\d{10}` Match 10 digits
- `\z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/hVNC1mxFCgcwWk) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/n4NiOt)

```
str = "19097147835"
str.gsub(/\D/, '').match(/\A1\K\d{10}\z/) do |match|
    puts match[0].to_i
end
```

Output

```
9097147835
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```rb
str.gsub(/\D/, '').sub(/\A1(?=\d{10})/, '').to_i
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/p7jKu3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hPSoc6/2).

The regex matches

- `\A` - start of string
- `1` -  a `1`
- `(?=\d{10})` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Non regex example:

```
str = str[1..] if (str.start_with?("1") and str.size > 10)
```

Regexes are powerful, but not easy to maintain.